# How do I get the output of the function in Groovy

Tags: groovy

```
  static def StartMonth() {
     def date = new Date().format('MM')
     def month = date.toInteger()

     if (month > 6) {
        month = month - 6 
     } else if (month <= 6) {
        month = (month + 12) - 6
     }

  }

  static void main(String[] args) {
      StartMonth();
  } 
}
```

I have this and the output will be 4 (right now in October) and I want to retrieve that value so that I can have a new variable `newDate = *startDate output* + '25/2019'` but I do not know how to *get* the value back. (I am very new to this, I usually program in Javascript and even then I am still a beginner)

Thank you

Comment: use `return (XYZ)` statement in function to return something. where `XYZ` expression ot variable.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_methods.htm

Answer (score 0):

In groovy you can return a value using the return value (as you can do in javascript). If there is no return a method returns the last value assigned (month in your case).

So you can either add `return month` in your StartMonth method. Or you can keep it as it is and just print it:

```
  static void main(String[] args) {
      println StartMonth()
  }
```